# Change default music app to Spotify

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth, huawei, spotify

Whenever I use Spotify over bluetooth and try to use my car's controls it, simply pauses the Spotify music and launches the default music player.
The Spotify music plays just fine, however, when there comes input from the Bluetooth, it pauses and starts the default music player.

Spotify is not listed in Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps -> Music, only Google Play Music and the default music player is listed on my Huawei P7.
I've tried using several softwares including Default App Manager, Better Open With, A2DP Volume and Bluetooth Connect and Play - however none work.

It would seem like when I click on the car's input it transmits it to the phone over BT, however, since the default music player is the default player it starts that app instead of Spotify.

Comment: Spotify cannot be your default music app, it can't play the appropriate file types registered as "music" files. I have had this problem on several phones. never did find a solution that was acceptable for using controls in the car for Spotify, always had to use the phone's controls.

Comment: So, I would have to use Google Music instead?

Comment: I didn't say that, I said controlling Spotify with your car controls is difficult (I won't say it's impossible, but I never found a solution) but if you want to use your vehicles controls, then apparently you need to use an app that can be set as the default music player, so whether it is Google Play, N7Player, PowerAmp, doubleTwist, BlackPlayer, or whatever, it doesn't necessarily have to be Google Play.

Comment: Here's your misconception: Spotify is **not** a music player app. It is an application that accesses its own database of music files and play them. It doesn't play any other sound files. So technically, it doesn't qualify as a music player.

Comment: Thanks SarpSTA and Acejavelin. I've decided to use Google Music until I found a workaround, even though I prefer Spotify. Thank you for your clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Google Assistant to "change the song". It works perfectly. 
Start a random song on Spotify.
Say "Ok Google" and wait for Assistant to pop up.
Say "Play the next song"
And she does it.
Works like a charm, as long as your phone's microphone works properly.

Comment: Thank you. The issue was also resolved by upgrading my phone (and Android version).
But it was ment more for a car with a dash, so having to say it each time would be a little bit of a hassle.

Comment: Actually, tbh it works perfectly in my car. I guess it depends on the make of the car too. I press "seek" on my car and the song changes. I have a Hyundai. Considering its a two year old post...I hope the new Spotify/Android/Car upgrades would've solved the problem already 

Comment: Yep. Android upgrade fixed it.